# How to apply bevel to inner corners

Tags: edges, bevel

I want to apply a bevel function to the inner corner below:

[image: before apply bevel]

But when I do ctrl-b, it gives:

[image: after apply bevel]

which is not smoothing edges. I looked at some other questions, there seemed to be something wrong with my topology but not sure how to fix that. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Bevel works on inner corners just as well... your screenshot looks like you have duplicate geometry in the corner. Press A to select all, then M > Merge > By Distance.

Comment: Hello, since it's not possible to see the scale of your object (visible in object mode in the N-Panel->Items->Scale), I can only guess. So I'd like to ask if you applied the transformation, specifically scale (Can be applied by pressing "Ctrl+A"->Scale). Without scale applied, bevels will not work as intended, rather they will be scaled based on the object, BUT will look wrong. Even with the object looking right, a few operations will result in unexpected results. Thus my comment and recommendation to always apply scale.

Comment: @Xylvier I thought about the scale as well, but since the outer corners are beveled correctly and the inner corner bevels absolutely not a bit in one direction (which would suggest a scale of 0 in this direction which is obviously not the case), so I'm quite sure that the scale is no matter if applied or not, at least even in all directions.

Comment: Try to merge by distance ... probably some edge duplication.

Comment: Thanks! @GordonBrinkmann, sorry for the late reply! It is working after I merged by distance, I am really glad about this! Thanks!

Comment: @vklidu Thank you too!

Comment: Sorry ... I didnt read whole Gordon's post :) +1